# Pivot columns with multiple instance (rows) of attribute

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery

I've searched far and wide and haven't found an answer to this specific case, and wasn't able to adapt some of these solutions.

First of all, my data is a long list of attributes and their values for every product, structured like this:
[image]

[Structured Initial Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT2rq.png)

Note that some products have a single value per attributes, but (and here's my problem) some products have different values for the same attribute.

When I pivot the table in PowerQuery, i get errors where the products have multiple instances of the same attributes.

The resulting table that i'm looking for would be structured like this:
[image]

[Structured Final Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJpAK.png)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: can likely do it, but why? The initial data structure is much more desirable

Comment: The data needs to be in this format to import it into an ERP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Source,{{"Products", Order.Ascending}, {"Attributes", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Sorted Rows", {"Products"}, {{"data", each _, type table}}),
#"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Index1", "data", {"Attributes", "Values"}, {"Attributes", "Values"}),  
mGroup = Table.Group(#"Expanded data" , {"Attributes","Products"}, {{"GRP", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index2", 1, 1), type table}}),
#"Expanded GRP" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(mGroup, "GRP", {"Values", "Index", "Index2"}, {"Values", "Index", "Index2"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded GRP", "Row#", each [Index]+[Index2]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index", "Index2"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Attributes]), "Attributes", "Values"),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Row#"}),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{"Products", "Each", "Pack"})
in #"Reordered Columns"
```

It groups on product and adds an index. Then it groups on product and Attribute and adds another index. The sum of those two are a unique row number you can use for pivoting